# C - Using bit-shift operators for base conversion

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, shift

I'm trying to convert some data from hex to base64 in C, I found an algorithm online but I would really like to know how it works rather than just implenting it and firing it off.  If someone could please explain how the following is working I would appreciate it.  I have been reading about the shift operators and I don't seem to understand them as much as I thought I did...it's not quite clicking for me.

```
for (x = 0; x < dataLength; x += 3) 
{
  /* these three 8-bit (ASCII) characters become one 24-bit number */
  n = data[x] << 16;

  if((x+1) < dataLength)
     n += data[x+1] << 8;

  if((x+2) < dataLength)
     n += data[x+2];

  /* this 24-bit number gets separated into four 6-bit numbers */
  n0 = (uint8_t)(n >> 18) & 63;
  n1 = (uint8_t)(n >> 12) & 63;
  n2 = (uint8_t)(n >> 6) & 63;
  n3 = (uint8_t)n & 63;
```

This code was taken from Wikibooks, it is NOT mine, I'm just trying to understand the bitshifting and how it's allowing me to convert the data.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Source: [Base64](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64)

Comment: If you understand what the bitwise operators do, then what are you not understanding in the code?

Comment: You could add your understanding of `>>`, `<<` and `&` to the question - and then see if you still have a question.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it with my limited understanding.  Thanks again for any help.

Comment: 63 = 0b00111111, plus some understand of what @Arkadiy said you should try this yourself.(0b00111111 this is how it looks in a byte of memory in RAM, 0b means number is in binary, 00111111 is the binary number)

Comment: Bit shifts do exactly what the name implies. `n >> 1` means that the lowest binary digit of n is discarded, the next highest becomes lowest and so on. For example, `00011001 >> 1` results in `00001100`. There is more to it for signed integer types (sign bit is propagated), but the essence is the shift. A combination of shift and bit mask (`&` operator) allows you to take a bunch of bits from the middle of the word and treat them as a separate number.

Comment: It's just aligning a digit and then masking the rest out several times. Nothing complicated is going on.

Comment: @Arkadiy The sign is not necessarily propagated with signed integers. It is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the input data is not hex as you say. It's simply data stored as bytes. The code will give you the base64 representation of it (although the code you posted lacks the part which will map `n0`, `n1`, `n2`, `n3` to printable ASCII characters).

Suppose the first three bytes of the input are (in binary representation, each letter represents a 0 or 1):

```
abcdefgh, ijklmnop, qrstuvwx
```

The first part of the code will combine them to a single 24-bit number. This is done by shifting the first one 16 bits to the left and the second one 8 bits to the left and adding:

```
  abcdefgh0000000000000000      (abcdefgh << 16)
+ 00000000ijklmnop00000000      (ijklmnop << 8)
  0000000000000000qrstuvwx
  ------------------------
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
```

Then it separates this into four 6-bit numbers by shifting and and'ing. For example, the second number is calculated by shifting 12 bits to the right and and'ing with 111111

```
n     =   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx

n>>12 =   000000000000abcdefghijkl
63    =   000000000000000000111111

And'ing gives:
          000000000000000000ghijkl
```

Comment: Wow, that actually makes a lot of sense to me now.  Thank you very much!  I was not expecting it to become that clear.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is a bit of explanation..

data[x] is an array of chars, a char is usuall 8bits.. (random 8bits number 01010101)
n is a 32bit number here is a random 32bit number(01011111000011110000111100001111)think there are 32bits there :)

remember n is 32bits and data is only 8bits.. lets go through the first line

```
 n = data[x] << 16;
```

<<16 has precedence over the equal sign so its evaluated first.

data[x] << 16 means move the bits in memory that data[x] represents by 16bits to the left.
suppose data[x] = 'a' this is represented by 01100001 in memory(1 bytes), so lets move is 16bits to the left

```
n = 00000000 01100001 00000000 00000000
```

next we have

```
if((x+1) < dataLength)
 n += data[x+1] << 8;
```

this says move the next char data[x+1] 8 bits and add it to n; so lets move it 8 bits first

```
( I assumed it was 'a' again)
00000000 00000000 01100001 00000000 
(this is done in some register in your processor)
```

now lets add it to n

```
00000000 01100001 01100001 00000000
```

next part is

```
 if((x+2) < dataLength)
 n += data[x+2];
```

lets do the same thing here, notice there is no bit shifting, since the last 8bits of n are free!! all we need to do is add it to n

b = 01100010 (assumed data[x+2] = 'b')
    adding it to n

```
  00000000 01100001 01100001 01100010
```

great so now we have a 24bits number(actually n is 32bits but the last 24bits is what we need)

next part

```
n0 = (uint8_t)(n >> 18) & 63; 
(take note n0 is only 8bits wide or a single unsigned byte)

take n and move it to the left by 18bits and "and" it with 63

n = 00000000 01100001 01100001 01100010
n moved 18bits to right is  00000000 00000000 00000000 00011000

now n is cast to an unsigned int of 8bits (uint8_t)

so now it becomes 00011000

last part is the & operator(bitwise and) 

    00011000 & 
    00111111
n0= 00011000
```

now repeat this for the rest

Comment: Wow very thorough, this is great! I wish I could select two answers for the green check mark.   I appreciate your time in writing this, it will help me a lot.