# using Bit Shift operations to convert from decimal to hex in Java

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

If I convert decimal 127 to hexadecimal in Java it will be 7f.
I can get the same output using:

```
(1 << 7) - 1 = 127
 0x7F = 127
```

I am trying to convert a decimal value `36028797018963967`.
In hex it will be:

```
0x7fffffffffffff
```

How can I represent this in bit-shift? For example, the output should be (with the `?` filled in):

```
(1 << ?) - 1 = 36028797018963967
```

Any (Java) code to get the output in this format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Using bit-shift operators for base conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884181/c-using-bit-shift-operators-for-base-conversion)

Comment: your question is not really `Java` specific.  The answer may be found here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884181/c-using-bit-shift-operators-for-base-conversion

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with decimal to hex conversion. You're trying to convert **a** number (in any representation) to left-shifting a single bit and then subtracting one. This will only work for a limited set of numbers - and it's not decimal to hex conversion.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know a method to calculate the `x` in `(1 << x) - 1 = input`, where the `input` is `36028797018963967` or `127` in your examples?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `long` or `BigInteger`.

```
public void test() {
    // Shifting to get the number.
    long l = (1L << 63) - 1L;
    System.out.println("" + l + " -> " + Long.toHexString(l));
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(63).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    System.out.println("" + bi + " -> " + bi.toString(16));
    bi = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(55).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    System.out.println("" + bi + " -> " + bi.toString(16));
    // Finding the amount to shift - it's easiest using BigInteger
    System.out.println(bi.bitLength());
}
```

Prints

```
9223372036854775807 -> 7fffffffffffffff

9223372036854775807 -> 7fffffffffffffff

36028797018963967 -> 7fffffffffffff

55
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood OP's description, but isn't this doing the reversed of what is asked? How I understand the question is calculating `x` in `(1 << x) - 1 = input`, for any possible `input` (where the `127` and `36028797018963967` were examples given). But perhaps I just misunderstood. I'll ask OP to verify.

Comment: Ah, smart. It's indeed just `.bitLength()`. Hadn't thought about that. +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println((1L << 55) - 1); //36028797018963967
```